# Is there any way to get only "My Contact" from my gmail account using api?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, socialauth, google-content-api

I made the following call to the Contacts API

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&access_token=<<access_token>>&max-results=5000&v=3.0
```

It return a list of all my contact gmail contacts. I want only the Contact that I added into book.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How was the contact you are looking for added?

Comment: thanks for correcting..Now i got the solutions
first i call  https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full api after getting group id i passed that id to  https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contact/default/full?group=<<getid>>

Comment: Could you explain more your solution ? I'm not finding the Group ID with the first API call.

Answer (score 1):

The contacts that you add to your address book manually go into the "My Contacts" group. This group is marked with `<gContact:systemGroup id="Contacts"/>` in the [contact groups feed](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#working_with_contact_groups). You can retrieve the contacts within a group by adding the query parameter `group={group id}` to your contacts feed query, where `{group id}` is the ID of the group.

Comment: for getting group_id i need to to call one more api https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/group/default/full, is there any way to direct get only my contacts